# Replace characters by key binding in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

How to write a key binding to replace specific character to another one?

For example I want to replace "[" and "]" to empty string "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, to make a custom key binding you would need to write a plugin in Python to do the finding and replacing, as there are no built-in commands for doing so. However, what you want to do is easily accomplished using the **`Find -> Replace...`** dialog. Make sure the regular expressions button is selected, then put `\[|\]` in the `Find What:` box, and nothing in the `Replace With:` box (it's best to put your cursor in there and delete everything, just in case there are invisible characters such as spaces or tabs there). Hit <kbd>Replace</kbd> to replace characters one at a time, or <kbd>Replace All</kbd> to replace all of them in one go.